# How to retrieve a value from a recordset that is not a return value or output parameter using vb6

Tags: stored-procedures, vb6, ado

I have a stored proc on an existing 3rd party application (SQL 2005) that I wish to interact with.

It is an insert statement followed by a select statement as follows;

```
  
    Set @CustomerId = Cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() As [int])

    Select @CustomerId
```

Using VB6 how do I access the value of @CustomerID?

```
set rs = cmd.Execute
```

is not returning a resultset as expected...

**[Edit]**

*rs.Fields.Count is 0.*

Any attempt to access the resulting recordset, like **rs(0).Value** simply causes an "Item not found..." error.

Comment: Er, guys, there is no rs(0). That's the meaning of rs.Fields.Count=0, and the "Item not found" error.

Comment: Just to clarify, I edited the question thanks to the comments from Pax and JP. (I will now make that clearer too.) Sorry.

Comment: @Stuart Helwig: If my answer doesn't quite work, it might be useful to say so in a comment to my answer. You don't have to accept it just because someone said so. Anyway - since I don't know exactly what you are dealing with, I can only answer by making a guess, not with 100% working code.

Comment: Absolutely. You ask a specific question, and the answer that solves the specific problem best should be the accepted one - even if you found it yourself. Yes, I have edited my answer since it didn't work at first. After I tested it, I put up a changed version that at least worked in my little test case "SELECT 'foo'; SELECT 17;". But I see now that there is one more bug in my code. I fixed it, give it another try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that your stored procedure is returning more than one recordset.

If this is the case, you can use the [`NextRecordset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539(VS.85).aspx) method to iterate through them.

MSDN:

> - If a row-returning command executes successfully but returns no records,
>     the returned Recordset object will be
>     open but empty. Test for this case by
>     verifying that the BOF and EOF
>     properties are both True.
> - If a non–row-returning command executes successfully, the returned
>     Recordset object will be closed, which
>     you can verify by testing the State
>     property on the Recordset.
> - When there are no more results, recordset will be set to Nothing.

This means I would suggest something like this to solve your problem:

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute

''# fetch the first value of the last recordset
Do Until rs Is Nothing
  If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
      ''# You can do a different sanity check here, or none at all
      If rs.Fields(0).Type = adInteger Then
        CustomerId = rs.Fields(0).Value
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Set rs = rs.NextRecordSet
Loop

MsgBox CustomerId
```

Comment: This code seems to need a "rs.Open" call straight after the execute to get it to work? Is that right or am I missing something?

Comment: When you execute a command, you get a recorset (or a bunch of them) back. They are open or closed, depending on whether they are result of a row-returning operation or not. If one of them is closed, it means that it was produced by an INSERT, for example. It does not mean that it must be opened. Your SELECT statement is a row-returning operation. It's attached recordset will be open, so I just check for "If rs.State = adStateOpen". All closed recordsets carry not much information other than that their statement was executed. They can be skipped in the loop.